# Loading resources from a jar within Java Web Start

Tags: java, jar, resources, java-web-start, embedded-resource

I am trying to load a number of resources in a Java Web Start(JWS) application.

I have tried loading images using:

```
private Image fetchImage(String path, String refname) {
    // check to see if the reference already exists else load it.
    if (images.containsKey(refname)) {
        return images.get(refname);
    } else {
        try {
          //return ImageIO.read(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(path));
            return ImageIO.read(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I get an IllegalArgumentException: input == null! at fetchImage

I've been reading this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306965/getting-resources-from-jar-in-a-java-webstart-application)

And have tried the solution to add classpath in my maven-jar-plugin pom.xml

at this [page](http://lopica.sourceforge.net/faq.html#listresources) I read the following:

> Java doesn't currently support a method to list all resources in a
>   jar. You can only retrieve one resource at a time.

Well I'm trying to load all my resources at a time. So have they solved this issue in JWS or do I have to remove each resource and reload it each time I need it?

my jar resources are at root so for example

my path would be:

```
this.fetchImage("images/image1.png", "image1");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306965/getting-resources-from-jar-in-a-java-webstart-application?lq=1

Comment: Yes I know you can solve this but I find it strange Java can only load one resource at a time. And I want if possible an other solution to this.

Comment: You can also preload resources with the [splash screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html).

Comment: `ClassLoader.getSystemResource(path)` but it is **not** A System resource.  Just use `this.getClassLoader().getResource(path)`.

Comment: Using `URL url = loader.getResource(path);    ImageIO.read(url);`  did the trick for me, I was a bit confused with Java loading only one resource at a time (topic with the answer is quite old) so could be fixed now.